# Exchange - Removing word "EXTERNAL" from Subject line when replying to an external email

Tags: outlook, spam-prevention, exchange-server-2013

We have Exchange server 2013. I am testing a security method to warn users when external emails are received. This is I am doing by putting "EXTERNAL" text in front of subject-line of incoming emails except if the email-subject already has the text. This is working fine.

Now, what I am trying to do is to remove the text "EXTERNAL" when user will reply to the email. I am having a hard time getting a way to achieve it. Exchange rules, so far I have looked into, does not have anything to remove from subject-line, only to prepend.

How can I do it? My goal is to flag incoming external emails and show it users Outlook client in a way so users would see. I want to use Exchange server built-in functionalities, or from Outlook if the settings can be managed by group-policy and users wont be able to change it.
Thanks and appreciate your help.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know the answer but my search for a way to strip "[External]" and "[EXT]" from the subject line of all incoming emails is what brought me here. It seems IT in so many companies has decided this is a great idea and I just want to share my thoughts that it is a HORRIBLE idea and I wish everyone would stop doing it.  You can no longer group all emails by subject line and bring everything together, which is seriously inefficient.  There HAS to be a better way to teach your employees to not click on spam/scam links than messing with the existing subject lines.  This may be my pet peeve of the century.

Comment: Since this isn't an answer you should add it as a comment to the question if you want.